# Function hiding in R

Tags: r, function, scope

Consider the following `file.r`:

```
foo = function(){}
bar = function(){}
useful = function() {foo(); bar()}
```

`foo` and `bar` are meant only for internal use by `useful` - they are not reusable at all, because they require very specific data layout, have embedded constants, do something obscure that no one is going to need etc.

I don't want to define them inside `useful{}`, because then it will become too long (>10 LOC).

A client could do the following to import only `useful` in their namespace, and still I am not sure if that will work with `foo` and `bar` outside visibility:

```
# Source a single function from a source file.
# Example use
# max.a.posteriori <- source1( "file.r","useful" )
source1 <- function( path, fun )
{
  source( path, local=TRUE )
  get( fun )
}
```

How can I properly do this on the `file.r` side i.e. export only specific functions?

---

Furthermore, there is the problem of ordering of functions, which I feel is related to the above. Let us have

```
douglas = function() { adams() }
adams = function() { douglas() }
```

How do I handle circular dependencies?

Comment: you want there to be _no way_ to call food/bar directly? if so define them in the scope of useful. having a restriction on the number of lines of code in a function seems... odd.  if not, you can literally put your functions into a mini-package and only export useful. I have no idea what you mean by your second question; it seems sufficiently orthogonal to be its own question

Comment: you could also create an environment into which you create foo/bar. a lazy version is my_env = list(foo ={}, bar = {}), then call my_env$foo() in useful, etc. my_env will be visible in the lazy version.

Comment: Another trick is to start their names with a period, `.foo` but they would still be available to the user. However, they wouldn't show up in `ls()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by setting the binding environment of your `useful` function, as in the code listed below. This is similar to what packages do and if your project gets bigger, I would really recommend creating a package using the great `devtools` package.

If the functions `foo` and `bar` are not used by other functions I would just define them inside `useful`. Since the functions are quite independent pieces of code it does not make the code more complicated to understand, even if the line count of `useful` increases. (Except of course if you are forced by some guideline to keep the line count short.)

For more on environments see: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

```
# define new environment
myenv <- new.env()

# define functions in this environment
myenv$foo <- function(){}
myenv$bar <- function(){}

# define useful in global environment
useful <- function(){
  foo()
  bar()
}

# useful does not find the called functions so far
useful()
# neither can they be found in the globalenv
foo()
# but of course in myenv
myenv$foo()

# set the binding environment of useful to myenv
environment(useful) <- myenv
# everything works now
useful()
foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use packages. They were created for such situations. But still you cannot hide the functions itself in pure R.

Comment: You can do anything a package does by attaching environments the right way, still your recommendation to write a package is quite right.

Comment: @snaut, no you cannot do _anything a package does by attaching environments the right way_. Nevertheless you can solve OP's problem with environments. Which solution I do not recommend unless there is a good reason to do this.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment. (It also seems to be wrong on the specific point of the question although the advice to make a package seems correct if not really a coding response..)

Answer (score 1):

In order to encapsulate foo and bar you need to implement a `class`. The easiest way, in my opinion, to do that in R is through `R6classes`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html#private-members. There you have the example on how to hide the `length` function.